# What is the best way to detect triangle-to-triangle intersections in three dimensions?

Tags: java, math, 3d, collision-detection, collision

I'm writing my own 3D engine ([which can be found here](https://github.com/alyxferrari/jse3d)) in Java and I'm trying to implement collision events. How can I tell if two 2D triangles intersect in 3D space? My end goal is to have a method that would take the six 3D points of the two triangles as arguments and return a boolean, true if the two triangles intersect. Something like this:

```
// where the Vector3 class has three fields, x, y, and z
boolean triangleIntersect(Vector3[] triangle1, Vector3[] triangle2) {
    // do stuff with triangle1[0] through [2] and triangle2[0] through [2]
}
```

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585459/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-detect-triangle-triangle-intersections) already, but it only covers 2D. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: Another one: [Find whether two triangles intersect or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113344/find-whether-two-triangles-intersect-or-not)